Is move-constructing an attribute of a specialized classes unspecified?
Consider the class Dog inheritng from Animal:
class Animal { … };

class Dog: public Animal {
 public:
  Dog(Dog&& other)
    : Animal(std::move(other)),
      breed(std::move(other.breed)) {
  }

 private:
  std::string breed;
};

The move constructor starts by constructing the parent object with std::move(other).
However, the standard library says that:

[After the move operations,] the moved-from objects shall be placed in a valid but unspecified state.

If I understand correctly, this means that the object pointed to by other is now in an unspecified state. This means that the next line constructing the attribute breed will result in an unspecified value.
Is this correct?

You are not the standard library, you do whatever you like in move constructors. Move constructors won't do anything beyond what you wrote, and unless you go crazy and delete this in it, there's nothing wrong.

After Animal(std::move(other)) the base class is in a state that the author of Animal controls by his/her design of the Animal move constructor.  Clients of Animal should not assume any specific state unless the author of Animal has documented such a state.
Theoretically, the author of Animal could have designed the Animal move constructor to assume that it is a subobject of Dog, and to reach into Dog and fiddle with the data member breed.  This would be highly unorthodox to do so.  A good design of Animal would not normally assume things like what classes have derived from it.
In general, assuming well-behaved code, the base class Animal does not know it is derived by Dog and its move constructor does not alter the derived class' data members.  Certainly if Animal's move constructor is supplied by the compiler, it does not do this.  The compiler supplied move constructor moves only its own bases and members (in that order, and in declaration order).
The move constructor you show for Dog is the generally accepted correct move constructor, and is identical to the move constructor that the compiler would supply, i.e. that generated by Dog(Dog&&) = default;.
As Pepijn Kramer notes in the comment below, one should design all of your special members together (your destructor, default constructor (if you have one), copy members and move members).  They all interact with each other.
And if you have any doubt about what "move does", one of my better descriptions of it in terms of generated object code appears in this answer near the end under the subtitle: So what does move do in terms of generated object code?

With the added note that if you add a move constructor you should also think about adding move assignment. And think about what your copy constructor, copy assignment and the default constructor should do (rule of 3/5/0)

What I'm more interested in is knowing whether a conforming compiler would be able to optimize away the line breed(std::move(other.breed)), on the basis that the value of other.breed is unspecified.

No such optimization is allowed.  The value of other.breed is not unspecified, unless a user-written Animal move constructor has purposefully made it so.  And even in this case, the compiler is not allowed to optimize away the move construction from other.breed.  If the Animal move constructor is compiler-supplied, then other.breed is definitely not unspecified.  "Unspecified value" != "Undefined Behavior".
